# Chrome extension create new tab and send message from popup.js to content script of new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension where my popup.js receives a message from a content script on the current page and creates an array. Then on a button press, popup.js creates a new tab (which has a content script running) and sends that content script a message containing the array.

My popup.js:

```
//this message is sent from a different content script (for current page), not shown here
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {

    if (request.action === "getSource") {
        var arr = JSON.parse(request.source);

        //create new tab 
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "newtab.html"}, function(tab){

            //send message to new tab
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id{
            action: "getDataArray",
            source: JSON.stringify(arr)
        });
    }
});
```

newtab-contentscript.js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {

      if (request.action === "getDataArray") {
        $("#result").html(JSON.parse(request.source));
      }
});
```

newtab.html:

```
<script src="newtab-contentscript.js"></script>
```

Problem: The newtab-contentscript.js never seems to receive the message.

Are the any mistakes with how I am creating a tab or sending the message. Do you have any suggestions to how to fix this issue?

Comment: I guess ( haven't dig into the source code of extension platform) maybe `$(document).ready` is too late to receive messages from `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. 

However, I believe moving message logic to background (event) page and starting the message passing from `newtab-contentscript.js` is a good way, in this way you could control when to start sending the message.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically an answer. The timing issue may be confirmed by comparing timestamps of `console.log` inside the callback and on the first line of the new tab's content script.

Comment: Thank you for the input! @HaibaraAi could you please elaborate on your suggestion? Are you suggesting that I create a new tab from my background page instead of sending it to popup.js? I attempted this but chrome functions such as creating tabs is not available to background scripts.

Comment: I also tried moving the listener in newtab-contentscript.js outside the $(document).ready and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, I guess maybe `$(document).ready` is too late to receive messages from `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, you can test it by comparing timestamps of `console.log` inside the callback and on the first line of the new tab's content scripts, as @wOxxOm mentioned.

I just suggest moving message logic to background (event) page and starting the message passing from `newtab-contentscript.js`, in which you could control when to start sending the message.

A sample code

background.js

```
let source = null;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // sent from another content script, intended for saving source
    if(request.action === 'putSource') {
        source = request.source;
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'newtab.html' });
    }
    // sent from newtab-contentscript, to get the source
    if(request.action === 'getSource') {
        sendResponse({ source: source });
    }
});
```

newtab-contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'getSource'}, function(response) {
    $('#result').html(response.source);
});
```

Comment: This just made my day thank you for posting the solution!