# opening new tab and performing actions on the new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

extension script:

```
function newtab() {
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":domain,"selected":true}, function(tab) {
        //--
    });
}
```

In my extension script I am opening a new tab with some domain. I want to be able to check if the dom in that new tab is loaded and then execute some operations on the dom in the new tab.

I checked the chrome extension documentation but could not find any appropriate method to achieve it.

Be my guiding light please.

Comment: Use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). There many answers showcasing this method, so I think you can find plenty of examples.

Comment: okay thanks @wOxxOm :)

Comment: Example for a simple case: [How to check how many elements of a certain type has a page with Chrome Extension Dev](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30380827)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension create new tab and send message from popup.js to content script of new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296583/chrome-extension-create-new-tab-and-send-message-from-popup-js-to-content-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are the only part of the extension that can access/modify the DOM.

You can use the so-called [Programmatic Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) to add a content script to the newly opened tab:

```
function newtab() {
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":domain,"selected":true}, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
}
```

`.executeScript()` is subject to [`run_at` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), that defaults to `document_idle`. This guarantees that the script will only execute after *static* DOM is completely loaded.

In case of dynamic DOM (page's scripts create more DOM after the static content has loaded), even *defining* "tab is loaded" state is problematic. [Listening to DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener) can help you.

A couple of notes:

- Programmatic Injection into a new page requires [host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) for the page. You would need a broad permission such as `"*://*/*"` or `"<all_urls>"` if you do not know the domain in advance.
- `"document_idle"` does not guarantee that all *resources* are loaded, e.g. an `<img>` tag may already exist but the image is not yet loaded. See the `run_at` documentation for details and advice.
- You can use a callback for `.executeScript()`, which may be the simplest way to pass some reply back to the script, but make sure you understand the [signature of the expected callback](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-executeScript-callback).

Comment: Thank you so much @Xan. I had solved this problem but your answer was very informative anyway :)