# Chrome extension - open new tab from popup and send there a message

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs, popup, listener, message

I need to find a solution for this task:

1. Open specified web site from list of websites in popup window
2. Run a specified content script operation over this website.

So I need to specify witch part of the content script should be executed when the website is opened. Therefore I'm trying to send a message from popup to newly opened tab in order to specify what should be executed:

In **popup.js:**

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#grantexpert').click(function () {

      var newURL = "https://www.grantexpert.sk";
      chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL }, function(tab) {

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "action_example"});
        });

      });

    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

In **content.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    switch(request.type) {

      case 'action_example':
        alert('running action-example');
        break;

    }
  }    
);
```

Bu this does not work and alert is not showing. There is no error in console of any tab/popup. Is it a wrong approach? How could it be accomplished?

---

**Update**
I cannot use the solution form this answer:[Chrome extension create new tab and send message from popup.js to content script of new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296583/chrome-extension-create-new-tab-and-send-message-from-popup-js-to-content-script) because there is a message sent from content script, but i need to send a message from popup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension create new tab and send message from popup.js to content script of new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296583/chrome-extension-create-new-tab-and-send-message-from-popup-js-to-content-script)

Comment: I cannot manage how to modify my script by that answer

Comment: @Incredible, In the Question, you state "there is a message sent from content script". However, that is not shown in the code you have provided, nor is any capability of the popup to receive such a message. Are you needing to exchange messages after the tab opens, or just send a single message from the popup?

Comment: I mean in that answer marked as duplicate is "a message sent from content script", not in my question. Yes I need only single message from popup.

Comment: Please provide a complete [MCVE], including a *manifest.json* (where you, presumably, define a `content_scripts` entry for your content script & `browser_action` popup) and enough of your HTML for the popup to actually test and duplicate the problem.

Comment: Providing a [mcve] is good idea because *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the situation and test solutions. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the situation. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: @Incredible, as the dup link said, it's likely the content.js is not fully loaded when you create the new tab. It's suggested to start the message from content.js and move your previous popup logic to background page.

Comment: @Makyen, sorry I changed my code but I'm sure there was no problem in other files or code that is not shown here. Everything else works fine just this specific dont.

Answer (score 1):

I found few comments on SO that it is too soon to send message to tab's content script right after the creation of the tab, so probably it is true (verified source needed).

I found another solution:

In **popup.js** I'm sending message for background.js (that a "test" should be executed):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#grantexpert').click(function () {

      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

        // message for content scripts
        // chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "start-test", test: "grantexpert"});

        // message for background scripts
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "start-test", test: "grantexpert"});
      });

    });
  });
```

In **background.js** I'm listenig to the message from popup.js (case "start-test"), creating new tab and setting global variable testname (what test is running an what is current step of test - one step is one pageload):

```
var step = 0;
var test = 'no-test';

// Message listener
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

  switch(request.type) {

    case "start-test":
      startTest(request.test);
      break;

    case "is-test-running":
      sendResponse({test: test, step: step});
      break;

    case "increment-step":
      step = step + 1;
      break;

    case "end-test":
      test = 'no-test';
      alert('Koniec testu');

  }

  return true;

});

function startTest(testname) {

  test = testname;
  step = 1;

  var newURL = "https://www.grantexpert.sk";
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
  alert('ZAČIATOK TESTU: '+test);

}
```

In **content.js** on every pageload (including tab creation) im sending a message to backgorund.js and awaiting response (checking if the test is running - if yes, specified part of code should be executed in content.js according to what test and what step is running):

```
// every pageload
$(document).ready(function() {

  // check if test is running
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "is-test-running"}, function(response) {

     switch (response.test) {

       case 'no-test':
         // do nothing if no test is running
         break;

       default:
         // increment step of test on pageload if test is running
         chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "increment-step"});
         // calling custom external testing functions by eval
         eval('test_'+response.test+'('+response.step+');');
     }
  });


}, true);
```

---

So the point is not to send a message from popup to newly created tab an it's content script (that some action has to be executed), but send a message from content.js on pageload and request information from background.js about what action has to be executed. `"What action has to be executed"` is stored in background's global variable, which can be set by message from popup.js

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use the tab parameter in your callback after creating a new tab? 
This code should send a message to your newly created tab:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL }, function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {type: "action_example"});
});
```

Comment: Even this does not work. No event is fired, no alert in message listener of content script is shown.