# Inject html as the result of an API Call Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

**The Question**

*How do I take the json result from and API call and inject the result into and html page?*

**The Context**

As part of a web extension I am working on, I call and API for a resulting json.

my `popup.html` has a button click that calls a `call.js` file.

**call.js** (example)

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:body,
        headers: headers,
        success:function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              // use return json to update html
              // maybe open html for injection here as
              // var url = chrome.extension.getURL('location.html')
              // chrome.tabs.create({url: url, active: true});
            }
```

Interms of flow, i'm not sure how to pass the result of the api call, in and effective way, to a scrip that will inject HTML into the `location.html` file.

I tried the following flow

> Get API Json -> store json in localStorage -> open `location.html` url
>   -> have a content script that runs an `injection.js` file one `https://*location.html*` appears -> inject required elements

but the json was to large for local storage, and honestly, I'm unsure if that flow was even correct. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? I feel this is a standard functionality of web extensions, but for some reason, I cannot put this piece of the puzzle together.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a content script if `location.html` belongs to your extension. Pages within extension have the same permissions as popup page. So just add JS into `location.html` that will receive the response via [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use massage passing.

in your content script

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(req =>{
if(req.action === "showJSONFromPopup"){
 showJSONResult(req.data)
}
})
```

in your popup script

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:body,
        headers: headers,
        success:function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true, active:true}, tabs=>{
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "showJSONFromPopup", data})

})
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! however, following @hindmost's comment i put the listener in a script that `location.html` calls in the header. and I activated the url with `chrome.tabs.create({url: url, active: true});` right after `console.log(data)`, but for some reason the listener is not executing, any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks I was able to get this working be following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296583/chrome-extension-create-new-tab-and-send-message-from-popup-js-to-content-script) answer,but your answer provided a great start and helped me down the path.